# Authorization in .NET Core 3: Order in which requirements are being executed

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I am imposing different policies to be satisfied in order to execute certain actions and I'd like to decide the order in which these policies have to be exectued. If a user is not authenticated, I should not check if it has permissions or not.

In startup I have:

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
 {
     endpoints.MapControllers()
         .RequireAuthorization("UserIsAuthenticated")
         .RequireAuthorization("UserIsRegistered");
 });
```

and then I use the default `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]` attribute and my `[MyAuthorize]` attributes.

The order in which these polices should be executed is:

- First, `UserIsAuthenticated`, to check if the user is authenticated.
- If they are, it should check `UserIsRegistered`.
- Finally the attributes should be applied.

In my case order matters, because I have

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => { options.InvokeHandlersAfterFailure = false; });
```

(if a user is not authenticated, I can't check their claims and it makes no sense to check the following policies).

However, in some cases I've seen that the attributes are being evaluated before the Authentication policies.

Is there a way to impose the order of the requirements?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom `AuthorizeMultiplePolicyFilter` to check these policies manually.Apply the filter to global then it will be excuted before action/controller filters.

```
public class AuthorizeMultiplePolicyFilter: IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    private  IAuthorizationService _authorization;
    private  string[] _policies;


    public AuthorizeMultiplePolicyFilter(string[] policies)
    {
        _policies = policies;
    }

    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Account"))
        {
            return;
        }

        _authorization = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IAuthorizationService>();
        foreach (var policy in _policies)
        {
            var authorized = await _authorization.AuthorizeAsync(context.HttpContext.User, policy);
            if (!authorized.Succeeded)
            {
                if(policy == "UserIsAuthenticated")
                {
                    context.Result = new RedirectResult("/Account/Login");
                }
                if(policy == "UserIsRegistered")
                {
                    context.Result = new ForbidResult();
                }

                return;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeMultiplePolicyFilter(new string[] { "UserIsAuthenticated", "UserIsRegistered" }))
        );
```

Comment: In "Authorization" subsection here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#routing-startup-code it says "When using endpoint routing, we recommend against configuring <xref:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter> and instead relying on the Authorization middleware.". It seems this is not the recommended solution. Actially, I'm doing this precisely because I've removed some filters :(